# Putting the words in a string into a list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm new to python and I'm trying to take words in a string and put them into a list, but I'm having trouble.
This is what it should look like:

Input: `sentence = "abcde that i like."`

Output: `list_of_words = ['abcde', 'that', 'i', 'like.']`

This is what I've tried:

```
word = "" 
list_of_words = []
sentence = "abcde that i like."
for letter in sentence:
  if letter != " ":
    word += letter 
  else:
    list_of_words.append(word)
    word = ""
print(list_of_words)
```

When I run the code the output is:

`['abcde', 'that', 'i']`

I'm trying to figure it out why the last word isn't included in the list.

Comment: You could always use `.split()`, eh. As for why the last word is not included, try walking through the final few iterations of the loop yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know .split() existed that's super useful. The last word isn't appended because the sentence doesn't end with a space, totally didn't realize that. I went over the final few interations a couple of times but for some reason I didn't go all the way to the end.

Comment: You're only checking spaces, not periods or other punctuation

Answer (score 1):

You shoul simply use `str.split()`:

```
>>> sentence = "abcde that i like."
>>> list_of_words = sentence.split()
>>> list_of_words
['abcde', 'that', 'i', 'like.']
```

If you want better results without punctuations, such as the period '.' in the demonstration, you should try regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
['abcde', 'that', 'i', 'like']
```

Read more here: [re — Regular expression operations — Python 3.8.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)!